# Can't iterate through each property of a custom object

Tags: vb.net

I have this class:

```
Public Class clsServCasam
    Public ID As Long
    Public CANT As Decimal
    Public PRICE As Decimal
End Class
```

I create a variable of that type and get the object from an API result:

```
Dim myObj As clsServCasam()
Dim rsp As HttpWebResponse = CType(rq.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
If rsp.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK Then
    Using sr = New StreamReader(rsp.GetResponseStream())
        myObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of clsServCasam())(sr.ReadToEnd())
    End Using
```

Then I try to get the field names from the object:

```
For Each p As System.Reflection.PropertyInfo In myObj.GetType().GetProperties()
    Debug.Print(p.Name, p.GetValue(myObj, Nothing))
Next
```

But, instead of class fields (ID, PRICE, ...) I got:

```
- Length
- LongLength
- Rank
```

### Update

As Steven Doggart pointed out, the above loop won't work because it looks for properties rather than fields.  So, I tried changing the loop to this:

```
For Each p As FieldInfo In myObj.GetType.GetFields()
    Debug.Print(p.Name)
Next
```

But now I'm getting no results at all.

Comment: Why do you need reflection at all? Can't you just read the property value of each item (a `clsServCasam` instance) from `myObj` (an array of `clsServCasam`)? As in `For Each item As clsServCasam in myObj Console.WriteLine(item.ID) (...)` etc.

Answer (score 2):

In your code, `myObj` is not declared as `clsServCasam`.  Rather, it is declared as `clsServCasam()`, which means it's an array of `clsServCasam` objects.  So, when you use reflection to iterate over its properties, you're getting the properties of the array rather than the actual `clsServCasam` type.

For instance, this would work more like you're expecting:

```
For Each item As clsServCasam in myObj
    For Each p As PropertyInfo In item.GetType().GetProperties()
        Debug.Print(p.Name, p.GetValue(item, Nothing))
    Next
Next
```

However, I think you'll find that that still won't work because it iterates over the properties rather than the fields.  In the definition of the `clsServCasam` class, all of the members are fields rather than properties, so the only properties that it have would be ones that are inherited from `Object`.  You will need to either iterate over the fields using `GetFields`, like this:

```
For Each item As clsServCasam in myObj
    For Each f As FieldInfo In item.GetType().GetFields()
        Debug.Print(f.Name, f.GetValue(item))
    Next
Next
```

Or you'll need to change them to properties:

```
Public Class clsServCasam
    Public Property ID As Long
    Public Property CANT As Decimal
    Public Property PRICE As Decimal
End Class
```

Or, if you are using an older version of the VB compiler which doesn't support auto-properties:

```
Public Class clsServCasam
    Public Property ID As Long
        Get
            Return _id
        End Get
        Set(value As Long)
            _id = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property CANT As Decimal
        Get
            Return _cant
        End Get
        Set(value As Decimal)
            _cant = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property PRICE As Decimal
        Get
            Return _price
        End Get
        Set(value As Decimal)
            _price = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _id As Long
    Private _cant As Decimal
    Private _price As Decimal
End Class
```

Comment: Hi.If I change the to property: Public Property ID() As Long  I got Error Property without a 'ReadOnly' or 'WriteOnly' specifier must provide both a 'Get' and a 'Set'.

Comment: I changed definition to Dim myObj() As clsServCasam but for    myObj.GetType.GetFields()  I got {Length=0}

Comment: @mrapi `Dim myObj() As clsServCasam` means exactly the same thing as `Dim myObj As clsServCasam()`.  Both declare a variable called `myObj` as an array of `clsServCasam` objects.  As far as the error about the Get and Set being required, that's because you're using an older version of the VB compiler, before auto properties were added.  I'll update my answer to show the syntax without the use of auto properties.

Comment: after the edited code above I got: ?myObj.GetType().GetProperties()
{Length=7}
    (0): {System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo} and still got Length.. for p.Name

Comment: Ok, and what are the 7 properties?

Comment: sorry I have 7 fields.only 3 I put above

Comment: OK, so do you still have a question?

Comment: If I put class definition as my first post, for fields I got  myObj.GetType.GetFields() I got {Length=0}

Comment: Well, you'd have to show the code, because it works for me.  `GetType(clsServCasam).GetFields()` returns an array of 3 `FieldInfo` objects.

Comment: Yes. I want to get fields name from the object.I need to create a table based on them

Comment: @mrapi Do you intend for `myObj` to be an array of `clsServCasam` objects, or just a single `clsServCasam` object. As Steven pointed out, both `Dim myObj As clsServCasam()` and `Dim myObj() As clsServCasam` are declaring an array. If you want a single object, you need `Dim myObj As clsServCasam`

Comment: myObj  is an array populate from a api result

Comment: As we've said multiple times, `myObj.GetType` will not return the info for `clsServCasam` because `myObj` is not declared as `clsServCasam`.  It is declared as an array of `clsServCasam` objects.  So, when you iterate through the list of fields, you are looking at the list of fields in the array object, not at the list of fields in each item in the array.

Comment: If you actually used the code from my second example, where it first iterates through the items in the array, and then has an inner loop that iterates over the fields in each item, then it would have worked.